# Fusionauth Saml login with groups membership

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, fusionauth

We want to use Fusionauth SAML2.0 identity provided for SSO and at the same time want the logged in user to be added as member of some groups based on claims in SAML response. As per the documentation there is way to register user with roles in application but could not find a way to add user as a member too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way to manage group membership as part of a SAML login reconcile.

This is partially covered in this feature request https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/229.

Please upvote that feature request, and add a comment to describe your use case if it is not covered in the main description.

This type of functionality is on the roadmap.